# Is there a way to read content of C++ raw string literal from non C/C++ file?

Tags: c++, file, include, string-literals

Is there a way to read content of C++ raw string literal from non C/C++ file (at compile time - i.e. make it hard-coded into resulting unit?

The C++ has nice raw string literals e.g.

```
const char* const cstring = 
R"myheredoc(
       do ;*!$%@#
       whatever 
       you want here
)myheredoc";
```

Is there however a way how to read the content of the raw string from a file which is non C++ (e.g. example configuration file).

I can imagine that this can be done by build system, just want to know that I did not miss anything from the great new C++ features.

Answer (score 4):

Currently C++ has no way to accomplish it, short of relying on the preprocessor and the build system.

While you *could* accomplish it with an auto-generated header/source file that is `#include`ed by the preprocessor, that is a somewhat sorry state of affairs. So there is currently a paper in flight for C++20, proposing the aptly named [`std::embed`](https://wg21.link/p1040). It will allow to do what you are after, pretty much, if it is ever voted into the C++ standard. So stay tuned.

Comment: If OP is using Linux or another OS that provides the [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) program, generating said header can easily be done with `xxd -i sourcefile`, which gives you an array of unsigned chars holding the contents of the file.

Comment: @Shawn - Whether or not the process is complex or not, does not change that fact it is a step done *outside* the language. Needing to use `xxd` still falls into the premise of this question.